# Text widget does not update with value change - Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management

I wanted my widget to reload with text update. I have a column that's displayed with elevation in `showGeneralDialog` that return `WillPopScope`. In it, I have a `CircularProgressIndicator` that shows up until a sync in the background is done. Below that, I want to show a text indicating the progress of the sync like 'Sync 1 of 10'...The number should change dynamically after each sync is done. I have the provider ready, 'SyncProvider'.

````
 showLoadingDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {      
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              height: isMobile ? 105.h : 300.h,
              width: isMobile ? 105.w : 300.w,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: pure_white),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        appIconLogoOnly,
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        height: isMobile ? 40.h : 250.h,
                        width: isMobile ? 40.w : 250.w,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: ColorfulCircularProgressIndicator(
                          colors: app_colors,
                          strokeWidth: 2.2,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          initialColor: app_colors[0],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: isMobile ? 10.h : 20.h,),
                  DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: isMobile ? 9 : 15,
                          color: const Color.fromARGB(221, 80, 79, 79),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                      child: Text(
                          "Sync ${ Provider.of<SyncProvider>(context, listen: false).currentSyncProgress} of 10")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}```


Appreciate the help!


I tried to get the value by using `Provider.of<SyncProvider>(context, listen: false).currentSyncProgress` but the value is not updating, stays at 0 which I initialized in the `SyncProvider` class.
````

Answer (score 0):

Separate the return Widget in a StatefulWideget, `showGeneralDialog` doesn't have a state that's why it didn't change.

```
showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
         return MyWidget();   
      },
    );
```

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: But I am using Provider, do I need to use stateful widget too? The model(SyncProvider) class is responsible for any variable update and the UI should only subscribe to the model.

Comment: Yes, you need a stateful widget! it's not about the Provider

Comment: The showGeneralDialog doesn't have a state

Comment: Thanks. But I used a Consumer with SyncProvider, and for the builder: context, syncProvider instance and child. And I returned Text("Sync  ${syncP.currentSyncProgress.toString()} of 10"). That worked.